# Querying JSON array from Postgres using Rust/Diesel

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, rust, rust-diesel

I've seen several questions on Stack saying to use serde_json::Value as the type for a JSON returned value from PostgreSQL. This, unfortunately, does not seem to be working for me. I have an array within Postgres of test questions (question_list JSON[] NOT NULL) and need to query this array into a vector, as shown below. When I go to compile, I get the error: `the trait diesel::Queryable<diesel::sql_types::Array<diesel::sql_types::Json>, _> is not implemented for TestStruct`

I do know that if I change values to i32, String or anything else, and change the associated schema to the same, it works fine. This leaves me with the impression that I'm doing something wrong with JSON and/or possibly the array itself.

I have the struct:

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Queryable)]
struct TestStruct {
    question_list: Vec<serde_json::Value>,
}
```

and the query

```
pub fn min_repro_func() -> Result<TestStruct, diesel::result::Error> {
    tests::table
        .select(tests::question_list)
        .first::<TestStruct>(&mut establish_connection())
}
```

My schema shows:

```
table! {
    use diesel::sql_types::*;

    tests (test_id) {
        test_id -> Int4,
        question_list -> Array<Json>,
    }
}
```

Diesel Version: 2.0.4
PostgreSQL version: 13

Comment: https://docs.rs/diesel/2.0.4/diesel/prelude/derive.Queryable.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is not that anything is wrong with your types, but a relative obscure limitation in diesel. It's not related to the json type there. For reference the following setup fails as well with a similar error message:

```rust
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Queryable)]
struct Test {
    id: i32
}

pub fn min_repro_func() -> Result<Test, diesel::result::Error> {
    tests::table
        .select(tests::test_id)
        .first::<Test>(&mut establish_connection())
}
```

produces the following error message:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Test: diesel::Queryable<diesel::sql_types::Integer, _>` is not satisfied
    --> src/main.rs:18:24
     |
18   |         .first::<Test>(conn)
     |          -----         ^^^^ the trait `diesel::Queryable<diesel::sql_types::Integer, _>` is not implemented for `Test`
     |          |
     |          required by a bound introduced by this call
     |
     = help: the trait `diesel::Queryable<(__ST0,), __DB>` is implemented for `Test`
     = note: required for `Test` to implement `FromSqlRow<diesel::sql_types::Integer, _>`
     = note: required for `diesel::sql_types::Integer` to implement `load_dsl::private::CompatibleType<Test, _>`
     = note: required for `SelectStatement<FromClause<table>, SelectClause<id>, NoDistinctClause, NoWhereClause, NoOrderClause, ...>` to implement `LoadQuery<'_, _, Test>`
     = note: the full type name has been written to '/tmp/diesel_test/target/debug/deps/diesel_test-417f66cdf189eb90.long-type-11591175215402042757.txt'
```

This also contains a hint what's wrong there as part of the first help line:

```
= help: the trait `diesel::Queryable<(__ST0,), __DB>` is implemented for `Test`
```

which basically says that `Queryable` is only implemented for a query that returns a tuple with a single element, while your query returns the plain element.

Changing the query to

```
pub fn min_repro_func() -> Result<Test, diesel::result::Error> {
    tests::table
        .select((tests::test_id, ))
        .first::<Test>(&mut establish_connection())
}
```

fixes the problem.

Now that's obviously some limitation in diesel. It would be great to fix that but as soon as diesel would try to provide both impls: For the plain element and for tuples it would run into problems with conflicting trait implementations. Therefore it was chosen to only provide the tuple impls in this case, as these are really useful for selecting more than one column. Providing both impls likely requires language level changes (like specialization or negative impls).

Comment: This unfortunately did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Well in that case the code provided above is incomplete because it works for me. If you need further help you need to provide a complete minimal reproducible example.